# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]' on a 2 dimentional array

Tags: c#, .net, int, return

In the below code I get

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

The line causing the error is

```
return firstNum - secondNum;
```

This is my code.

```
namespace Determinant
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] BerekenDeterminant (int[,] determinant)
        {
            int firstNum = determinant[0,0] * determinant[1, 1];
            int secondNum = determinant[0,1] * determinant[1, 0];
            return firstNum - secondNum;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] aMatrix =
            {
                {2,4},
                {3,5}
            };
            Console.WriteLine($"Determinant van matrix is {BerekenDeterminant(aMatrix)}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initializing multidimensional arrays in c# (with other arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205402/initializing-multidimensional-arrays-in-c-sharp-with-other-arrays)

Comment: just change you return type to int instead of int[]. int[] is array type

Comment: What is expected behavior (cba to google what is determinant)? If you want to return `int` then simply change return type in method signature from `int[]` to `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return new[] {firstNum - secondNum};
```

or just change return type to int only. Up to how you want to work with that method

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new array:

```
static int[] BerekenDeterminant(int[,] determinant)
    {        
        int firstNum = determinant[0, 0] * determinant[1, 1];
        int secondNum = determinant[0, 1] * determinant[1, 0];
        int[] inttab = new int[] {firstNum, secondNum};
        // or
        // int[] inttab = new int[] { firstNum - secondNum };
        return inttab;
    }
```